# an example for $\pi$-quasinormal subgroup but is not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you give me an example about a $\pi$-quasinormal subgroup but it is not normal subgroup?
P.s: $H$ is $\pi$-quasinormal subgroup of $G$ iff $HP=PH$, $\forall P$ is Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.
$K$ is normal subgoup of $G$ iff $Kg = gK$, $\forall g \in G$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $G=D_8$, the dihedral group of order 8. Take $H$ any subgroup of order 2, such that $H\cap Z(G)=\{e\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for a good idea.